# Two links appear as one in the Tour page

Tags: bug

The BH Tour page contains this list of things not to ask about:

[image: Don't ask]

The list has three obvious links to three different suggestions for where to ask instead.

But it *doesn't* have three links, it has four.
"Christian Doctrine" is actually two links, a different one for each word.

I discovered this by chance, having clicked the space between the two words and not getting a new page.

I wonder how many people have selected one of those links, not realizing that the other existed, and then wondered why they got redirected where they did.

Comment: Based on the other two hyperlinked words, it appears that “doctrine” is incorrect (aside from needing to be joined to “Christian”). Good catch!